# Facebook User Ids gets auto incremented

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook user ids which have the length 17 (ex: 012345678901234567) gets incremented or decremented when it's inserted into the DB column. It happens randomly, I checked the variables and values everything seems to be fine. I was still not able to find what's going wrong.

Comment: Please update your post with the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: @NishantGhodke I couldn't identify the source code that's causing this. I checked all possible code pieces. But everything was fine. There's mobile version of the application. So probably that may be causing it. And I don't have access to that. Sorry. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess you use Javascript and I would guess that you treat id as a number. You get rounding errors because Javascript handles ints bigger than 32 bits as floats.

Just always treat it as a string and you will be fine.